# Connecting an Android app to a database

Tags: php, android, database, android-studio

I'm trying to get my Android Studio register app to send information to the database. I'm using a WAMP server. Below is my Register.php code that was uploaded and if anyone sees anything wrong with it could you help to amend it?

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "users");

    $Name = $_POST["Name"];
    $DoctorNumber = $_POST["DoctorNumber"];
    $Password = $_POST["Password"];
    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO users(Name, DoctorNumber, Password) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "siss", $Name, $DoctorNumber, $Password);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

    $response = array();
    $response["success"] = true;  

    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Comment: You will have to have a rest api that your android app talks to that is setup in your php code. There are many tutorials out there, but you probably will want a framework to use for that.

Comment: `siss` < count those and the `?` and variables; they need to match

Answer (score 0):

You can't connect your Android (or even iOS) app directly to a MysQL database. You'll have to create a webapp that exposes it, and the use a library like Retrofit to make the http calls.